# Procedure "undeclared" despite execute being granted

Tags: oracle, permissions, plsql

I have created two identical procedures in two schemas. I have then granted execute on each procedure to a third schema. I call each procedure using the qualified object name. When calling the procedure in one schema there is no issue, when calling the second I get PLS-00302: component must be declared.

Why?

Here's the code I'm running, actual usernames/passwords have been obscured. Firstly the procedures are created in `USER1` and `USER2` and execute is granted to `USER3`

```
connect user1/password@db/db
-- */
create or replace procedure blah is
begin
  null;
end;
/

Procedure created.

grant execute on blah to user3;

Grant succeeded.

connect user2/password@db/db
-- */
create or replace procedure blah is
begin
  null;
end;
/

Procedure created.

grant execute on blah to user3;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then I connect to `USER3` and attempt to execute the procedures

```
connect user3/password@db/db
-- */
exec user1.blah

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

exec user2.blah

BEGIN user2.blah; END;

           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00302: component 'BLAH' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

As far as I can tell this doesn't appear to be a permissions issue (though it obviously is). The system privileges of the 2 users are identical, the following queries return no results:

```
select privilege, admin_option, common from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'USER1'
 minus
select privilege, admin_option, common from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'USER2';

select privilege, admin_option, common from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'USER2'
 minus
select privilege, admin_option, common from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'USER1';
```

Querying `USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD` in `USER3` returns the following, no differences

```
select * from user_tab_privs_recd where table_name = 'BLAH';

OWNER TABLE_NAME GRANTOR PRIVILEGE GRANTABLE HIERARCHY COMMON TYPE
----- ---------- ------- --------- --------- --------- ------ ---------
USER1 BLAH       USER1   EXECUTE   NO        NO        NO     PROCEDURE
USER2 BLAH       USER2   EXECUTE   NO        NO        NO     PROCEDURE
```

Comment: Exact same code is working fine for me as expected. You might be connected to different instance of database or something else.

Comment: I'd have mentioned if it was a RAC @JSapkota. There's only one instance, and this was run locally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be reproduced independently

Comment: That is kind of the point of the question @Phil, it's true. If I could reproduce it I wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: @Ben if you can't even reproduce it yourself, then there's something missing in your question, and we're unlikely able to help

Comment: I can't create a user with the necessary privileges in order to reproduce this, in fact I've proved that (as far as I know) the privileges are identical. Have I missed any sets of privileges?

Comment: Have you tried querying `DBA_OBJECTS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest way I can reproduce this is if there's a package in user3 with the same name as user2. It tries to find the procedure BLAH in the package user2 rather than in the schema user2.

So query `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='USER2'`

Comment: You, sir, are a miracle worker - that's the answer.